# PCI-DSS 1.3.3/1.3.5, restricting outbound access from DMZ to Internet

Tags: linux, centos, system-administration, pci-dss

we are in the process of obtaining for a PCI Level 1 and I'd really appreciate if anyone can help shed some light on the PCI-DSS 1.3.3 & 1.3.5 requirements which states:

1.3.3 - "Do not allow any direct routes inbound or outbound for traffic between the Internet and the cardholder data environment"
1.3.5 - "Restrict outbound traffic from the cardholder data environment to the Internet such that outbound traffic can only access IP addresses within the DMZ."

Right now, we are utilizing a Juniper SRX firewall and have webservers in DMZ, with mysql db servers in Trusted.
For Trusted, we just finished locking down all egress to public and had to setup a proxy server in DMZ that grabs updates (yum, clamav, waf-rules, etc ...) to get the updates from.

But we didn't really expect DMZ to also require a complete lockdown of egress as we've done on Trusted. And I do find this a bit of a challenges (unless I'm mistaken) to do an egress lockdown on DMZ, as our proxy also lives  there and needs an outbound access to public for grabbing updates and what not. Whitelisting them via IP's are challenging because 3rd party vendors have ever-changing IP's.

So my question is, just exactly how much "restriction" is required? For our Trusted, we have a "deny-all" egress and a whitelist of select IP addresses that it can access. Does DMZ also require this? Or can DMZ just have "deny-all" based on ports, which would make things a lot easier, as we won't have to worry about ever-changing IP addresses of mirrors and 3rd party services.

I found some proxy appliances that does intelligent filtering based on "host names", (in other words, dynamic IP whitelisting) but they do seem to cost quite a bit of money.

As you can see, I'm looking for some answers, our auditor isn't much of a help, he just says it needs to be locked down. If anyone here have experience with PCI auditing, I'd love to hear what you have to say.

Answer (score 1):

If you have restricted inbound and outbound access to your DMZ and there is no direct access from the DMZ to the Internet then you have met the requirements.

By using a proxy, most QSAs will agree that you have removed the direct access. If there are services for which proxies aren't available then you could either remove them from the same DMZ as the cardholder data environment (e.g. if they are not part of the immediate service) or discuss this with your QSA. It's possible you will need to implement compensating controls or look at other creative solutions.

You will need to convince your QSA that these are legitimate relaxations to the restrictions. This is really something where they should be able to look at your documentation and implementation and give you a straight yes or no.

As with many of the PCI requirements there is flexibility in the interpretation. You can find more about the intent of each requirement in this document: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/navigating_dss_v20.pdf

Comment: what if there are some services where proxies aren't applicable?